# "A good community size is 1000 people"

Tags: discussion, philosophy

Somewhere around the blogs etc documenting Stackoverflow beta, someone asked "what's a good community size," and someone (Jeff?) answered along the lines of "we found it really started to work when it went north of 1000 people." I can't find the attribution right now... what's the link?

Comment: Sounds like the adage "all you need are 1,000" true fans...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was me: [How many people do you need to a make a StackExchange site work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-many-people-do-you-need-to-a-make-a-stackexchange-site-work/3950#3950)

It was in reference to podcast 18. They were discussing the early Stack Overflow beta. At that point, 1,000 people had already answered a question with at least one up-vote (Teacher badge). The tone of the conversation was that Stack Overflow was declared "a success." I brought it up as a data point to consider. Not necessarily *a minimum* size for a "good community."

In more recent podcasts ([episode 70](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4269.html#)), they talk about the success of StackExchange sites and the minimum number of knowledgeable people needed to make a site worthwhile. Joel's response: The **minimum number of users needed answering questions: one**.

> Questions get asked + Questions get answered = Useful site